# iOS UIWebView totally fails to understand more than one @font-face?

Tags: ios, css, uiwebview, font-face, custom-font

Notice this simple css/html which is being displayed in a local UIWebView:

there's the simulator showing it...

[image]

Notice there are two @font-face definitions.

But ... ***only the second one works.***  If you swap them around, only the second one works.

[image]

So here ...

```
@font-face {
font-family:'aaa';
src: local('SourceSansPro-Regular'),
url('SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
font-family:'bbb';
src: local('SourceSansPro-BoldIt'),
url('SourceSansPro-BoldItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

**only "bbb" works**, the other one seems to be "cancelled".  Then here ..

```
@font-face {
font-family:'bbb';
src: local('SourceSansPro-BoldIt'),
url('SourceSansPro-BoldItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
font-family:'aaa';
src: local('SourceSansPro-Regular'),
url('SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

**only "aaa" works**, the other one seems to be "cancelled".

Here's how to do it in Swift,

```
// load a simple UIWebView (say, an "about" or "legal" screen)
// base is in template.html
import UIKit
import WebKit
class MinorWebView:UIViewController
    {
    @IBOutlet var wv:UIWebView!
    @IBInspectable var filename:String = "?"
    // for example, "about" for "about.html"

    ...
    func makeHtml()
        {
        print("making html for ... " ,filename)

        let ourSize = grid.yourSizeDecisionMechanism
        let sizeString = String(format:"%.0f", ourSize)

        let p1 = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("template", ofType: "html")
        var html:String = try! NSString(contentsOfFile:p1!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String

        let p2 = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: "html")
        let content:String = try! NSString(contentsOfFile:p2!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String

        html = html.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("STUFF", withString:content)
        html = html.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("SIZEPOINTS", withString:sizeString)

        print("Made html like this ---\n" ,html ,"\n------")

        wv.loadHTMLString(html as String, baseURL:nil)
        }
    }
```

Simply drag "template.html" and "about.html" in to the project (just as you would with an image); ensure they have target membership.

Comment: Have you tried WKWebView?

Comment: Thanks for asking Alberto; it seems to just completely fail in WK. (Uses only default type.)  Here, am really trying to get it to work in UIWebView, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in the `<style>` block: it starts with a `<meta>` element. This will throw the parser off; apparently it thinks that everything up until the first `}` is bad and needs to be discarded.

Solution: take the `<meta>` out of the `<style>`.

Comment: Just wondering, could I in fact end the meta?  `<meta id=...></meta>`  (Of course, moving it out of style - before style.)

Comment: Metas don't need to be closed; they're [void elements](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#void) without an end tag or content.

Comment: In XHTML, you can write `/>` at the end instead of `>`, but not `></meta>`.